# What is the icy humanoid creature?

Tags: boruto

> At the beginning of the new Boruto opening theme, an ice humanoid creature (that bears an uncanny resemblance to the incomplete Juubi)  is seen using its tail to enclose Boruto.

[image]
Its tail looks like some form of wood release mixed with ice release! And it's big enough to make Boruto look like a speck from the distance. It seems around the size of, if not bigger than, a Tailed Beast.

What is this monster?

Comment: http://narutofanon.wikia.com/wiki/Cryofication_Technique ??

Comment: @AnkitSharma looks like that wiki is everything about fanon (fanmade) entries, I'd be very skeptical about its canonicity...